# Accessing each pixel value from a numpy array in an efficient manner

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a pixel array of shape (height, width, channels) of an image and I want to process each pixel efficiently (I would be processing each pixel about 60 times per second)

Given a numpy pixel array of the sort: `pix = np.arange(60).reshape(4, 5, 3)`
I want to do something like:

```
for i in pix:
    for j in i:
        some_func(j)
```

but in a more efficient manner. I tried using `np.nditer`, but I could get it to access only the channel values and not the pixel as a whole

Comment: As long as `some_func` can only work with one pixel at a time, there isn't much you  can do.  In python, it's calling that function thousands of times that will be the main time consumer.

Comment: Even if you got it right `nditer` would not speed things up.

Comment: it depends from what `some_func` is. provide an example.